# Default font in UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, fonts, tableview

do you know what is the default cell's font showed in the UITableView of the Interface Builder? This one:

[image]

When I'm running the simulator I'm not getting that font.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"System Bold 20" or "Helvetica Bold 20" as far as iOS 5.0.1 and XCode 4.2.1 goes

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica Bold 23 ( 22 ~ 25 maybe )